# React & Typescript: nested defaultProps deep merge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm creating a React & Typescript component and need to define some default props which are objects with nested data. Here is a simplified example of my component:

```
type Props = {
    someProp: string,
    user: {
        blocked: boolean,
        active: boolean
    }
}

export const UserPage: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    (...)
};
```

Then I define default props like so:

```
const defaultProps: Props = { 
    user: {
        blocked: true
    }
}

UserPage.defaultProps = defaultProps
```

The problem is, if my component is called with the following props

```
<UserPage user={{ active: true }}/>
```

than the user object in the default props will be overwritten completely.

What is the best way to declare and merge props and default props with nested data?

Comment: Have a look at [defaultsDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaultsDeep) from lodash. Usage: `const props = defaultsDeep(defaultProps, userProps)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
const propsWithDefaults = Object.assign(defaultProps, props);
```